# Handlebars {{#with (lookup)}} not working in dynamic template

Tags: handlebars.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I'm currently trying to set up a dynamic template on sendgrid to inform participants, that signed up for an event, about their group allocation. For this I'm providing the following JSON

```
    {
    "name": "TestEvent",
    "date": "2023-03-06",
    "flights": 
        {
        "1": {
            "teeTime": "18:00",
            "participantIds": [
              "123456",
              "98765"
            ]
          }
        },
        "participants": {
          "123456": {
            "firstName": "Test",
            "lastName": "User",
            "flight": "1"
          },
           "98765": {
            "firstName": "Example",
            "lastName": "Participant",
            "flight": "1"
          }
        }
      }
```

What I'm trying to get from this is basically an Email along the line of this:

```
18:00 - Flight 1
Test User
Example Participant
(to be continued in case more Groups are provided in JSON, e.g.)
18:10 - Flight 2 
User 3
User 4
```

For this i set up the following structure in the dynamic template

```
     {{#each flights as | flight |}} 
        {{flight.teeTime}} - Flight {{@key}} 
        
        {{#each flight.participantIds as | participant |}}
            <br>
            {{#with (lookup @root.participants participant) as |participantDetails|}}
            
                {{firstName}} {{lastName}} 
                
            {{/with}}
            
        {{/each}}
        
     {{/each}}
```

When looking at the preview in the sendgrid code editor, all looks well:
[Sendgrid Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VugIx.png)

However when I send a Test-mail, I only get the "header" row. firstName and lastName are not getting resolved.

```
18:00 - Flight 1
```

I'm suspecting a problem within the `#with` block and already tried the following options. Actually all of them produce the correct results in the preview

```
{{#with (lookup @root.participants participant) as |participantDetails|}}

{{#with (lookup ../../participants participant) as |participantDetails|}}

{{#with (lookup @root.participants participant)}}

{{#with (lookup @root.participants [participant]) as |participantDetails|}}
```

Any Ideas why this is not working? Is there a limitation in nesting loops and with statements?

Comment: Out of curiosity: As you are aliasing each participant `as |participantDetails|`, would `{{participantDetails.firstName}} {{participantDetails.lastName}}` have any effect?

Comment: Thanks, actually have tried this before as well in multiple variations like `{{participantDetails.lastName}}`,`{{this.lastName}}` or just as it is above. Same behaviour. All works well in the preview pane but not in the actual message that is being sent